# launch(ProjectTaskManagementApp.class, args); ERROR

Tags: java

With the following code:

```
   launch(ProjectTaskManagementApp.class, args);
```

There is the error:

The method launch(Class, String[]) is undefined for the 
 type ProjectTaskManagementApp

Why is it doing this? Could anyone help resolve the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's doing that because there's no method `launch` that takes a `Class` object and an array of `String` as arguments in the class `ProjectTaskManagementApp`. The method you're thinking of may have a different name, or may take different arguments, or it may simply not be there.

Based on the fact that you're calling `launch` without an object reference, it looks like this call  is actually inside the definition of the class `ProjectTaskManagementApp`. Do you mean to be calling a `launch` method defined in this class, or it it defined in some other class? Do you mean to be calling `launch` via an object?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the class: `ProjectTaskManagementApp` does not contain the method with the *exact* parameters you are calling it with, or does not exist at all.